# SharePoint 2010 - Use FilterMultiValue in combination with documentSet (to filter document library)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, filtering, sharepointdocumentlibrary, document-set

Has anybody used the **FilterMultiValue** in combination with **DocumentSet**?

I have a list with 2 content types (1 = document and 2 = document set).
I have added 4 documents: 2 documents and 2 document sets. 
There is a column om my list (DWHID) that I want to use to filter the list. 1 document and 1 document set are linked to dwhid 5436. the other document and documentset are linked to dwhid 1234.

Now when I do this filter (?FilterField1=DWHID&FilterValue1=5436), everything works fine:
I get 1 document and 1 document set, as expected. The same for ?FilterField1=DWHID&FilterValue1=1234.

But when I use this filter (?FilterName=DWHID&FilterMultiValue=5436), the documents are filtered correctly but I see all the documentsets (the one linked to 5436 AND the one linked to 1234).

Any idea how to solve this? Or is it a bug?

Thx in advance!